# Dataframe conversion from Python to R: keep Python string as R chr not R factor

Tags: python, r, string, pandas, rpy2

First happy new year to everybody and happy coding for 2017.

I have a Python pandas dataframe that I need to convert to a R dataframe.
My Python pandas dataframe looks like this:

```
'data.frame':   302 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ typ     : chr  "page" "area" "par" "line" ...
 $ id      : chr  "page_1" "block_1_1" "par_1_1" "line_1_1" ...
 $ page    : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ area    : num  NA 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ par     : num  NA NA 1 1 NA 2 2 2 NA 3 ...
 $ line    : num  NA NA NA 1 NA NA 2 2 NA NA ...
 $ x1      : num  0 0.02 36.91 36.91 0.03 ...
 $ y1      : num  0 26.1 4.2 4.2 26.1 ...
 $ x2      : num  100 5.95 36.92 36.92 5.97 ...
 $ y2      : num  100 26.09 8.29 8.29 44.54 ...
 $ length  : num  100 5.93 0.02 0.02 5.93 ...
 $ heigth  : num  100 0.01 4.09 4.09 18.44 ...
 $ txt     : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
 $ strong  : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
 $ special : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
 $ AVGx    : num  50 2.98 36.91 36.91 3 ...
 $ AVGy    : num  50 26.09 6.24 6.24 35.31 ...
 $ SC_NR   : chr  "41151000029" "41151000029" "41151000029" "41151000029" ...
 $ DOK_LFNR: chr  "640" "640" "640" "640" ...
```

I am using:

```
pandas2ri.activate() 
pandas2ri.py2ri(dataframe)
```

and I got the following R dataframe:

```
'data.frame':   302 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ typ     : Factor w/ 5 levels "area","line",..: 3 1 4 2 1 4 2 5 1 4 ...
 $ id      : Factor w/ 302 levels "block_1_1","block_1_10",..: 77 1 78 28 12 89 39 216 21 100 ...
 $ page    : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ area    : num  NA 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ par     : num  NA NA 1 1 NA 2 2 2 NA 3 ...
 $ line    : num  NA NA NA 1 NA NA 2 2 NA NA ...
 $ x1      : num  0 0.02 36.91 36.91 0.03 ...
 $ y1      : num  0 26.1 4.2 4.2 26.1 ...
 $ x2      : num  100 5.95 36.92 36.92 5.97 ...
 $ y2      : num  100 26.09 8.29 8.29 44.54 ...
 $ length  : num  100 5.93 0.02 0.02 5.93 ...
 $ heigth  : num  100 0.01 4.09 4.09 18.44 ...
 $ txt     : Factor w/ 189 levels "","[e]","{minutes}",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 107 1 1 ...
 $ strong  : Factor w/ 3 levels "","0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ special : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ AVGx    : num  50 2.98 36.91 36.91 3 ...
 $ AVGy    : num  50 26.09 6.24 6.24 35.31 ...
 $ SC_NR   : Factor w/ 1 level "41151000029": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ DOK_LFNR: Factor w/ 1 level "640": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

The issue is that the R dataframe has *factor* type instead of *chr* type. I managed to fix it with R code:

```
i <- sapply(df, is.factor)
df[i] <- lapply(df[i], as.character)
```

Is there a way to do that during the conversion directly?

I am using :

```
python 2.7.12
rpy2 2.8.2
pandas 0.18.1
```

Thanks
Fabien

Comment: The constructor for `DataFrame` in rpy2 doesn't expose the parameter `as.is` available for the R function `data.frame`. Arguably a limitation. Probably worth opening an issue of rpy2's project page on bitbucket.

Comment: @lgautier : I will be happy to open an issue but can explain a little bit more what is `as.is` and what this is doing ? Thanks

Comment: @FabienTarrade - your comment should be made under my answer. And to be fair, initial question was answered to do type conversion in Python. The cleaning up needs was another issue, maybe deserving of another question. *None* types from database *Nulls* are familiar to Python experts.

Comment: @FabienTarrade : I confused the argument with the one in R's `read.table()`. The one I meant is `stringsAsFactors`.

Comment: @lgautier: thanks and done: [link to issue 392](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/392/the-constructor-for-dataframe-in-rpy2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider converting to character columns in Python by importing R's base package. Apparently, the `pandas2ri.py2ri()` method only uses the default features of R's `data.frame()` which renders characters to factors. Below uses the `rclass` method as described in [rpy2 docs](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/robjects.html#data-frames):

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

base = importr('base')
pandas2ri.activate()
...

# CONVERT PANDAS DF TO R DF
rdf = pandas2ri.py2ri(pydf)

# FIND COLUMN INDEX OF EACH FACTOR IN DF
factors = [i for i,col in enumerate(rdf) if col.rclass[0] == 'factor']

# CONVERT COLS ITERATIVELY
for f in factors:
    rdf[f] = base.as_character(rdf[f])
```

Comment: Sound great, thanks a lot. I will try that. Do you know which encoding is used  when as_character is called ? I am using UTF-8 and I need to keep such formatting.

Comment: Good question. Encoding in R usually goes by cpu locale. Don't know how that migrates in rpy2 between Python and R environments. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks it works but I had a do a lot of "clean up". When importing data from Oracle missing data are are label as None. If I just replace None by numpy.nan then during the conversion from Python dataframe to R dataframe the initial structure is not kept. If the python variable in your dataframe is an object (string) the you need to replace Noneby '' otherwise you need to replace None by numpy.nan and then it (almost) works. The last issue is that during the conversion it uses R default encoding which is not UTF-8 on my Windows machine.

Comment: sorry, you are right, I move the answer below your answer. The issue with the factor variable can be fix in Python as you mentioned it or in R as I did it. Ok next time I will open a new question for each topic. The issue is not only None but also NaN which is in Python of type float while in R NA can be used for anything if I am right.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to google a bit but I don't seem able to find a good documentation of `pandas2ri.py2ri(dataframe)` function.

The `R` `data.frame` function (and the `as.data.frame` function as well) has the boolean `stringsAsFactors` argument which, from the documentation is

> logical: should character vectors be converted to factors? The ‘factory-fresh’ default is TRUE, but this can be changed by setting options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE).

I guess the `pandas2ri.py2ri(dataframe)` function supports in some way this, and all the other optional arguments.

The following links will bring you to the full documentation of the `R` functions:

- [`data.frame`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/data.frame.html)
- [`as.data.frame`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/as.data.frame.html)

I'm sorry I can't help you more than this but I don't know the Python language nor the pandas package ;(

Comment: >>> I'm sorry I can't help you more than this but I don't know the Python language nor the pandas package ;( <<<  Then add this information as a comment, not answer.

Comment: Ah I see, my apologies!

Comment: yes, thanks for the info. I know the option stringsAsFactors = TRUE when creating a fresh dataframe in R. As you mention it, this need to be passed when calling pandas2ri.py2ri(dataframe) but I could find yet how to do that.